# SQL Two tables need to return values from either table based on a rank in a union

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables; tblORIG has all of the data and tblNEW has some newer updated data that is still pending approval so I can't merge or update.

I'd like to return the tblNEW row but if the NEW results aren't there I want to return the tblORIG row.

I've created a **UNION ALL** as a **FROM** sub query and given the tblORIG a rank of 2 and the NEW a rank of 1. At first I thought perfect I’ll just select my fields and a MIN(RANK). This doesn't work because the fields are sometimes different and Group By returns everything.

Current project applicable to *MSAccess* (Sigh) but I would like to know the answer in access or MySQL or Oracle.

Here is some simplified code to explain the problem.

```
SELECT U_TBL.NAME1, U_TBL.NAME2, MIN(RANK_VAL)
FROM 
(SELECT tblORIG.NAME1, tblORIG.NAME2, 2 AS RANK_VAL FROM tblORIG
 UNION ALL
 SELECT tblNEW.NAME1, tblNEW.NAME2, 1 AS RANK_VAL FROM tblNEW) AS U_TBL
GROUP BY U_TBL.NAME1, U_TBL.NAME2
```

I can't use a `Group by` Because Name1 and Name2 are different from one another in each table. They have Account_ID's and Yes they would be the same. **tblNEW** will always have a record in **tblORIG** but **tblORIG** will only sometimes have a record in **tblNEW**

I'll take suggestions for a better title of the question too.

Comment: I think you'll need to join the two tables together, using an outer join.  Then you can use coalesce (or whatever your platform of choice uses for that.  I think in Access you can use `NZ`.).  Something like `select coalesce(tblNew.col1,tblOld.col1)... from tableOld left outer join tableNew on...`.

Comment: What's the primary key? Account_ID?

Comment: @PederRice Yes both tables have IDs. I guess it would be called ORIG.KUNNR and NEW.KUNNR. Yes it is SAP data. If the table is in NEW it is also in Old. The NEW table is me cleaning up the OLD data. The project is so I can have it validated by some other team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea with the MIN, but that needs to be done with a sub-select. So something like:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, 1 AS Rank FROM A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, 2 AS Rank FROM B
) AllItems
JOIN
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        MIN(Rank) AS MinRank
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ID, 1 AS Rank FROM A
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, 2 AS Rank FROM B
    ) Ranks
    GROUP BY
        Ranks.ID
) LowestItems
    ON AllItems.ID = LowestItems.ID
    AND AllItems.Rank = LowestItems.Rank
```

Hope you can apply that to your specific situation.

Comment: Small modification from 
`AND AllItems.Rank = LowestItems.Rank` 
to 
`AND AllItems.Rank = LowestItems.MinRank`

I got it to work. Its not fast, but that is more on Access than anything. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT tblNEW.NAME1, tblNEW.NAME2, 1 AS RANK_VAL FROM tblNEW
UNION ALL
SELECT tblORIG.NAME1, tblORIG.NAME2, 2 AS RANK_VAL 
FROM tblORIG
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblNEW WHERE NAME1 = tblORIG.NAME1 AND NAME2 = tblORIG.NAME2)
```

That should work with MySQL.  Not sure about Access.

Comment: I wasn't able to make it work in Access, but I'll keep this method handy if I ever run across this in a better DB system. Thank you.